# How to modify the Bootstrap 3 grid so that it's behaviour is non-mobile (large screen) first?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less

The [Bootstrap 3 responsive grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is mobile first. That is to say that the media queries are defined using `min-width` rather than `max-width`, and if the media queries are not interpreted by the browser then the grid renders as a single 'tube of content'.

I have a client that wants their front-end to be based on Bootstrap 3, with the grid layout displayed in IE 8 even without JavaScript, ruling out [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for polyfilling the media query support in IE 8. They also want the site to behave responsively in mobile browsers, ruling out the completely [non-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) approach.

So the question is how can the Bootstrap 3 grid LESS CSS be modified so that it's behaviour is non-mobile (large screen) first?

I've searched for a solution, but I haven't been able to find any. I've started work on porting the grid behaviour to non-mobile (large screen) first myself but quickly ran into complexity. This feels like it should be a solved problem.

I've created a Codepen with with the Bootstrap v3.3.5 grid extracted as a [reduced test case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwOraX?editors=110). (The only code I've added that's not come directly from Bootstrap v3.3.5 is the `.show-grid` class from the docs to help visualise the layout).

Comment: Have you looked at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the layout still needs to work responsively in browsers that support media queries, hence the desire for the non-mobile first approach rather than disabling responsive entirely. I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Comment: IE10 and below will not be supported by Microsoft after Jan, 2016. Maybe, re-think this approach? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=internet%20explorer

Comment: Despite the lack of official support XP and IE 8 are still expected to account for a significant proportion of user for the client well into 2016.